# Citation when trying to go to the mechanic to fix the flat tire. Part 2.

Tags: traffic

I was in Massachusetts and had flat tires and was going to the mechanic to fix them. The police gave me a citation for "negligent operation of vehicles". I now find out that it has criminal application.

I would appreciate your advice whether it is fair. What will be the expected outcome? Should I get a lawyer?

I would appreciate your comments.

Comment: If money is less important then the consequences to you, get a laywer.

Answer (score 5):

The law says don't drive an unsafe vehicle on the road. You disobeyed the 
law. There were methods of having your tyres fixed without driving on the road (e.g. taking the tyres to the mechanic in a different vehicle, calling a mobile mechanic etc.) so you have no defence of necessity.

In all likelihood you will be convicted and penalised. You need legal advice.

Whether it's fair or not is a philosophical consideration, not a legal one.